# Unable to Validate Data error when using ValidateAntiForgeryToken ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have registration form in that i have Business keywords first search keywords then it display in list box then i select business keyword and select in another list box

[image: This is the form of business keywords]

When I post this form and redirect to next form then i got error unable to validate Data

[image: This is error message i have return]

I am also use machine key in my web.config file this problem error while migrating my website in another server i also change hosting provider then after i face same problem. I host my website in  IIS 7.5 so I need any settings in web.config file.
e
If i am using machine key tag in web.config file then Model is return null value so it gives error message object reference null i host my website in other free server then its work very file without any error message

I work this website offline very well and not getting any error message can any one suggest me the solutions

I am using Asp.net MVC 3 with c#.net razor view engine. I refer many website but i have not get any solutions. as per my knowledge do some settings in web.config file for IIS 7.5 but

I don't know which settings i do ? any person can test online of this website visit : contactsdetail.com and click on FreeListing tab then continue to complete this form then you get this error

if any one have any idea of this error please inform me.

Thanks in advance

I have first free listing View Page below the code :

**LocationInformation.chtml**

```
@{using (Html.BeginForm("LocationInformation", "FreeListing", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken("PostData");
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Local Information</legend>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContactsID)
            <br />
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    Business Name <span class="spanid">*</span></div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CompanyName, string.Empty, new { @class = "validationfont" })
            </div>
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    Building</div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Building)
            </div>
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    Street</div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street)
            </div>
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    LandMark</div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LandMark)
            </div>
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    Area<span class="spanid">*</span></div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AreaName, new { @id = "txtsearcharea" }) 
           @*     @Html.TextBox("AreaName", "", new { @id = "txtsearcharea" })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AreaName,null,new { @class = "validationfont" })
            </div>
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    City <span class="spanid">*</span></div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.CityName,new{@id = "txtsearchkey1"})
              @*  @Html.TextBox("CityName",, new { @id = "txtsearchkey1", @readonly = "readonly" })*@
            </div>
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    Pincode</div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pincode)
            </div>
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    State</div>
                @Html.TextBox("StateName", (string)ViewData["statenm"], new { @id = "txtsearchkey2", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
            <div class="divlabel">
                <div id="divlabeltype">
                    Country</div>
                @Html.TextBox("CountryName", (string)ViewData["countrynm"], new { @id = "txtsearchkey3", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
            <div>
                @{
      int newpageno = 1;
      if (Request.Params["page"] != null)
      {
          newpageno = int.Parse(Request.Params["page"].ToString());
          newpageno = newpageno + 1;
      }
       <div class="buttonsavecontinue">
         <div class="submitbutton"> 

                        <a href="#"><input type="submit" name="SaveContinue" value="Save & Continue" /></a> 
                         <a href="#">
                            <input type="submit" name="SaveExit" value="Save & Exit" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                     <div class="buttonrightalign">
                       <div class="submitbutton"> 
                          @Html.ActionLink("Next >>", "fl_Index", new { id = 2 })
                     @*  <a href="@Url.Content("~/FreeListing/fl_Index/2")"><input type="submit" value="Next >>" /> </a>*@ </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
  }
}
```

**FreeListingController**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = "PostData")]
        public ActionResult LocationInformation(string SaveExit, string SaveContinue, FreeListingTable model, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
        {
            db = new DirectoryDBEntities();
            if (Session["editcontactsid"] != null)
            {
                editcontactsid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["editcontactsid"]);
                contactids = editcontactsid;
            }
            if (Session["contactids"] != null)
            {
                contactids = Convert.ToInt32(Session["contactids"]);
            }
            if (Session["isnewuser"] != null)
            {
                isnewuser = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["isnewuser"]);
            }
            if (Session["fltable"] != null)
            {
                fltable = ((FreeListingTable)Session["fltable"]);

            }
            if (model.CompanyName == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CompanyName", "Please Enter Business Name");
                fltable.CompanyName = null;
                return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
            }


            if (model.AreaName == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("AreaName", "Please Enter AreaName");
                return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);

            }


            if (SaveExit == "Save & Exit")
            {


                if (model.CompanyName == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CompanyName", "Please Enter Business Name");
                    fltable.CompanyName = null;
                    return RedirectToAction("fl_Index", "FreeListing", new { id = 1 });
                }

                if (model.AreaName == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("AreaName", "Please Enter AreaName");
                    return RedirectToAction("fl_Index", "FreeListing", new { id = 1 });
                }


                if (contactids == 0)
                {
                    model.CityID = fltable.CityID;
                    model.CompanyName = fltable.CompanyName;
                    model.CityID = fltable.CityID;
                    model.ContactName = fltable.ContactName;
                    model.Designation = fltable.Designation;
                    model.PhoneNo = fltable.PhoneNo;
                    model.MobileNo = fltable.MobileNo;
                    model.MoblieNo2 = fltable.MoblieNo2;
                    if (fltable.LandMark != null && fltable.LandMark != string.Empty)
                        model.LandMark = fltable.LandMark;
                    else
                        fltable.LandMark = model.LandMark;
                    model.EmailID = fltable.EmailID;
                    model.Website = fltable.Website;
                    model.Pincode = fltable.Pincode;
                    var getareaid = db.AreaTables.Where(t => t.AreaName == model.AreaName).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (getareaid != null)
                    {
                        model.AreaID = getareaid.AreaID;
                    }
                    if (model.AreaID == null)
                    {
                        fltable.AreaName = model.AreaName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fltable.AreaID = model.AreaID;
                        ViewData["AreaID"] = model.AreaID;
                    }
                    model.IsPremium = false;
                    var getcitydata = db.CityTables.Where(t => t.CityID == model.CityID).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (getcitydata != null)
                    {
                        model.CityName = getcitydata.CityName;
                        model.CountryName = getcitydata.CountryTable.CountryName;
                        model.StateName = getcitydata.StateTable.StateName;
                        model.StateID = getcitydata.StateID;
                        model.CountryID = getcitydata.CountryID;
                        TempData["CityName"] = model.CityName;
                    }

                    model.Date = DateTime.Today.Date;

                    db.AddToFreeListingTables(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    contactids = model.ContactsID;
                    Session["fltable"] = fltable;


                    Session["contactids"] = contactids;
                }
                else
                {
                    FreeListingTable getcurrentdata = db.FreeListingTables.Where(t => t.ContactsID == contactids).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (getcurrentdata != null)
                    {
                        getcurrentdata.CompanyName = model.CompanyName;
                        getcurrentdata.Building = model.Building;
                        getcurrentdata.Street = model.Street;
                        getcurrentdata.LandMark = model.LandMark;
                        getcurrentdata.Pincode = model.Pincode;

                        var getareaid = db.AreaTables.Where(t => t.AreaName == model.AreaName).SingleOrDefault();
                        if (getareaid != null)
                        {
                            getcurrentdata.AreaID = getareaid.AreaID;
                            model.AreaID = getareaid.AreaID;

                        }
                        if (model.AreaID == null)
                        {

                            fltable.AreaName = model.AreaName;
                            model.AreaID = null;
                            fltable.AreaID = null;
                            getcurrentdata.AreaID = null;
                            getcurrentdata.AreaName = model.AreaName;

                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fltable.AreaID = model.AreaID;
                            ViewData["AreaID"] = model.AreaID;
                        }

                        if (model.CityName != null && model.CityName != string.Empty)
                        {
                            var getcityid = db.CityTables.Where(t => t.CityName == model.CityName).SingleOrDefault();
                            if (getcityid != null)
                            {
                                fltable.CityID = getcityid.CityID;
                            }
                        }

                        var getcitydata = db.CityTables.Where(t => t.CityID == fltable.CityID).SingleOrDefault();
                        if (getcitydata != null)
                        {
                            getcurrentdata.CityName = getcitydata.CityName;
                            getcurrentdata.CountryName = getcitydata.CountryTable.CountryName;
                            getcurrentdata.StateName = getcitydata.StateTable.StateName;
                            getcurrentdata.StateID = getcitydata.StateID;
                            getcurrentdata.CountryID = getcitydata.CountryID;
                            TempData["CityName"] = getcurrentdata.CityName;
                            model.IsPremium = false;
                        }
                        getcurrentdata.Date = DateTime.Today.Date;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        fltable = getcurrentdata;
                        model = getcurrentdata;

                    }
                }

                contactids = model.ContactsID;
                Session["fltable"] = fltable;
                model = fltable;

                if (model.ContactName == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ContactName", "Please Enter Contact Name");
                    fltable.ContactName = null;

                    return RedirectToAction("fl_Index", "FreeListing", new { id = 2 });
                }
                if (model.PhoneNo == null && model.PhoneNo == string.Empty && model.MobileNo == null && model.MobileNo == string.Empty)
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("MobileNo", "Please Enter Mobile No 1");
                    fltable.MobileNo = null;
                    return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
                }
                if (isnewuser)
                {

                    if (model.OldPassword == null || model.OldPassword == string.Empty)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("keyName", "Please enter old password");
                        return RedirectToAction("fl_Index", "FreeListing", new { id = 6 });

                    }
                    if (model.NewPassword == null || model.NewPassword == string.Empty)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("newpassword", "Please enter new password");
                       return RedirectToAction("fl_Index", "FreeListing", new { id = 6 });

                    }
                    if (model.NewPassword != null || model.NewPassword != string.Empty)
                    {
                        if (model.NewPassword != model.ConfirmPassword)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmPassword", "Password not match with new password");
                            return RedirectToAction("fl_Index", "FreeListing", new { id = 6 });
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

            }
            if (SaveContinue == "Save & Continue")
            {

                if (contactids == 0)
                {
                    model.CompanyName = fltable.CompanyName;
                    model.CityID = fltable.CityID;
                    model.ContactName = fltable.ContactName;
                    model.Designation = fltable.Designation;
                    model.PhoneNo = fltable.PhoneNo;
                    model.MobileNo = fltable.MobileNo;
                    model.MoblieNo2 = fltable.MoblieNo2;
                    model.EmailID = fltable.EmailID;
                    model.Website = fltable.Website;
                    if (fltable.LandMark != null && fltable.LandMark != string.Empty)
                        model.LandMark = fltable.LandMark;
                    else
                        fltable.LandMark = model.LandMark;
                    model.Pincode = fltable.Pincode;
                    var getareaid = db.AreaTables.Where(t => t.AreaName == model.AreaName).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (getareaid != null)
                    {
                        model.AreaID = getareaid.AreaID;
                    }
                    if (model.AreaID == null)
                    {
                        fltable.AreaName = model.AreaName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fltable.AreaID = model.AreaID;
                        ViewData["AreaID"] = model.AreaID;
                    }
                    model.IsPremium = false;

                    var getcitydata = db.CityTables.Where(t => t.CityID == model.CityID).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (getcitydata != null)
                    {
                        model.CityName = getcitydata.CityName;
                        model.CountryName = getcitydata.CountryTable.CountryName;
                        model.StateName = getcitydata.StateTable.StateName;
                        model.StateID = getcitydata.StateID;
                        model.CountryID = getcitydata.CountryID;
                        TempData["CityName"] = model.CityName;
                    }

                    model.Date = DateTime.Today.Date;
                    db.AddToFreeListingTables(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    contactids = model.ContactsID;
                    Session["fltable"] = fltable;
                    Session["contactids"] = contactids;
                }
                else
                {
                    FreeListingTable getcurrentdata = db.FreeListingTables.Where(t => t.ContactsID == contactids).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (getcurrentdata != null)
                    {
                        getcurrentdata.CompanyName = model.CompanyName;
                        getcurrentdata.Building = model.Building;
                        getcurrentdata.Street = model.Street;
                        getcurrentdata.LandMark = model.LandMark;
                        getcurrentdata.Pincode = model.Pincode;
                        //Contact information
                        getcurrentdata.ContactName = fltable.ContactName;
                        getcurrentdata.Designation = fltable.Designation;
                        getcurrentdata.PhoneNo = fltable.PhoneNo;
                        getcurrentdata.MobileNo = fltable.MobileNo;
                        getcurrentdata.MoblieNo2 = fltable.MoblieNo2;
                        getcurrentdata.EmailID = fltable.EmailID;
                        getcurrentdata.Website = fltable.Website;

                        var getareaid = db.AreaTables.Where(t => t.AreaName == model.AreaName).SingleOrDefault();
                        if (getareaid != null)
                        {
                            getcurrentdata.AreaID = getareaid.AreaID;
                            getcurrentdata.AreaName = getareaid.AreaName;
                            fltable.AreaID = getareaid.AreaID;
                            fltable.AreaName = getareaid.AreaName;
                        }
                        if (model.AreaID == null)
                        {

                            fltable.AreaName = model.AreaName;
                            model.AreaID = null;
                            fltable.AreaID = null;
                            getcurrentdata.AreaID = null;
                            getcurrentdata.AreaName = model.AreaName;

                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fltable.AreaID = model.AreaID;
                            ViewData["AreaID"] = model.AreaID;
                        }


                        if (model.CityName != null && model.CityName != string.Empty)
                        {
                            var getcityid = db.CityTables.Where(t => t.CityName == model.CityName).SingleOrDefault();
                            if (getcityid != null)
                            {
                                fltable.CityID = getcityid.CityID;
                            }
                        }


                        var getcitydata = db.CityTables.Where(t => t.CityID == fltable.CityID).SingleOrDefault();
                        if (getcitydata != null)
                        {
                            getcurrentdata.CityName = getcitydata.CityName;
                            getcurrentdata.CountryName = getcitydata.CountryTable.CountryName;
                            getcurrentdata.StateName = getcitydata.StateTable.StateName;
                            getcurrentdata.StateID = getcitydata.StateID;
                            getcurrentdata.CountryID = getcitydata.CountryID;
                            getcurrentdata.CityID = getcitydata.CityID;
                            TempData["CityName"] = getcurrentdata.CityName;
                        }
                        getcurrentdata.Date = DateTime.Today.Date;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        model = getcurrentdata;

                    }
                }

                contactids = model.ContactsID;
                Session["fltable"] = fltable;
                Session["contactids"] = contactids;

                return RedirectToAction("fl_Index", "FreeListing", new { id = 2 });
            }


            return RedirectToAction("fl_Index", "FreeListing", new { id = 2 });
        }
```

in fl_index/1  Means request the view of Location Information
same as fl_index/2 means request the view of Contact Information 
same as fl_index/3 Means request the view of Business Keywords which i post screen shots at the top of the question

so when i click save and continue and request to next page weather it is contactInformation of weather it is LocationInformation or BusinessKeywords

Answer (score 1):

Your form does not contain `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.

I don't see the `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` in your action methods, so I guess it is declared at a controller level... maybe it is affecting also to GET requests? Use the attribute in your POST methods only.

Try to do things in the straight way first : http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: Please check my question again i have updated i have problem due to migrating iis server 7 to 7.5 so what is the settings for that?